# Handle dynamic generated checkboxes in javascript

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dynamic

I am generating dynamic checkboxes with the functionality of radiobuttons

```
var foo = $("#foo");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
var descr = $('<br><tr><td><label> TEST_'+i+':</label></td><td colspan="2">' +
    '<div class="controls gprs_modbus_checkbox_' + i + '">'+
    '<label class="checkbox"><input class="chb" type="checkbox" value="option1" > GSM</label>'+
    '<label class="checkbox"><input class="chb" type="checkbox" value="option2" > RTU</label>' +
    '<label class="checkbox"><input class="chb" type="checkbox" value="option3" > TCP</label>'+
    '</div></td><td></td><td></td></tr>' );
    $(descr).insertAfter(foo);        
}

var m;
$('.chb').on('click',function() {
    m = $(this).closest('div').prop('class').split(' ')[1];
    console.log(m);
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    $('.'+ m +' >label> input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
    if(checked) {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    }
})
```

What I am trying to do is that when I click 'GSM', all others 'GSM's should be 'clicked' too. It supposed to react synchronized. But there must still be the possibility to select none of the checkboxes.

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/duzf1t44/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element. And secondly you can use checkbox value for select similar checkbox like following.

```
$(document).on('change', '.chb', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.chb[value=' + value + ']').prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/duzf1t44/4/)**

**UPDATE:** checkbox group to behave like radio button.

```
$(document).on('change', '.chb', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.chb[value=' + value + ']').prop('checked', this.checked);

    if (this.checked)
        $('.chb').not('[value=' + value + ']').prop('checked', false);
})
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/duzf1t44/6/)**

Comment: thanks for the fast response. But it should act like a radiobutton :(

Comment: thanks for the update. but unfortunately now i cannot have all checkboxes unchecked. min. none, max one option

Comment: You said `functionality of radiobuttons` thats why I do it like this. However see updated part of my answer. @moody

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your selector to match all inputs with class `chb` and with the same value as the input box that was just clicked. Then you just change their `checked` to match.

```
$('.chb').on('click',function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
  $('input.chb[value="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/duzf1t44/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending any dom element after(i.e. future element), $().on won't work with those element, try $(document).on('click','.class', function(){}); instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = $("#foo");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var descr = $('<br><tr><td><label> TEST_'+i+':</label></td><td colspan="2">' +
        '<div class="controls gprs_modbus_checkbox_' + i + '">'+
        '<label class="checkbox"><input class="chb" type="checkbox" value="option1"> GSM</label>'+
        '<label class="checkbox"><input class="chb" type="checkbox" value="option2"> RTU</label>' +
        '<label class="checkbox"><input class="chb" type="checkbox" value="option3"> TCP</label>'+
        '</div></td><td></td><td></td></tr>' );
        foo.append(descr);        
}


var m;
    $('.chb').on('click',function() {
        m = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      foo.find("input[value='"+m+"']").prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        foo.find("input[value='"+m+"']").prop('checked',false);
    }

    });
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some comment and which portion of the OP's code you have changed.